# Label Imported Font Error on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, fonts

I imported a font that is not supported by the Visual Studio 2012. The code is working but I'm having a problem when the label's boundary and a moving picturebox's boundary touched, the label is having an error (see link since I can't post image yet).

http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/4562/ybzy.jpg

The error occurs when the form where the 2 objects have been closed using Me.Close() and re-open again by Form.Show() and then the 2 objects touched each others' boundaries. For people wondering why I need to close and re-open forms, I need it for the next level of my simple game.

Note: Before closing the first form, I'll open another form where there will be many codes inside that form and before I close that form, I'll open the first form again.

Note: invaders.TTF is in my Debug folder.

Code for the module:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Text

Module Module1
    Public shoLevel As Short = 1

    Public Function custFont(data As String, ByVal size As Single, ByVal style As FontStyle) As Font
         Dim customFfont As Font
         Dim pfc = New PrivateFontCollection()
         pfc.AddFontFile(Application.StartupPath & data)
         customFont = New Font(pfc.Families(0), size, FontStyle.Regular)
         Return customFont
    End Function
End Module
```

Code for the first form (shows the level) that has a label and a moving picturebox.

Note: I didn't show the other timers that controls the other direction of the picturebox. Let's just assume that by moving straight up, the picturebox will hit the label.

```
Public Class Form1

     Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
         Label1.Font = custFont("\invaders.TTF", 20, FontStyle.Regular)
         Label1.Text = "L E V E L " & shoLevel
         Label1.Location = New Point((Me.Width - lblLevel.Width) / 2, (Me.Height - lblLevel.Height) / 2)
    timer1.Start()
     End Sub

     Private Sub timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timer1.Tick
         Static x as integer = 0
         picturebox1.Top -= 2
         x+=1
         If x >= 100 Then
              timer1.Stop()
              Form2.Show()
              Me.Close()
         End If
     End Sub
End Class
```

Code for the second form (Main Game) that has a label and a moving picturebox.

Note: The error occurs here too.

```
 Public Class Form2
     Dim blnNextLevel as Boolean = False

     Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
         Label1.Font = custFont("\invaders.TTF", 20, FontStyle.Regular)
         Label1.Text = "L E V E L " & shoLevel

        '*insert lines of codes here*'

         timer1.Start()
     End Sub

     '*timer that has a validation if it is ready for the next level*'
     Private Sub timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timer1.Tick
         '*insert lines of codes here*'
         '*Assuming that the blnNextLevel is now True*'
         If blnNextLevel = True Then
              shoLevel += 1
              Form1.Show()
              Me.Close()
         End IF
     End Sub

     '*Insert codes for other objects like timers for the moving pictureboxes*'
 End Class
```

Comment: You should create the PrivateFontCollection only once.

Comment: Changed the Dim pfc to Static but the line "customFont = New Font(pfc.Families(0), size, FontStyle.Regular" is havung a blue line of death saying that (see link since the desc. is long)... http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/7573/iffc.png

Comment: @HansPassant I just didn't use the pfc at the module. I just declare a pfc in each form. Really big thanks to you.